# Program freeze while using dispatcher.invoke

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have multiple categories in Database (Category, Subcategory).
I want to put the subcategories into the normal Categories.
This is my Method:

```
private void LoadCategories()
{
    connection = new MySqlConnection(conf.connection_string);
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM auftrags_typ_category";

    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    {
        try
        {
            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int categoryID = (int)reader["id"];
                #region Create Expander
                Expander cat_expander = new Expander();
                cat_expander.ExpandDirection = ExpandDirection.Right;
                TextBlock cat_name = new TextBlock();
                cat_name.Text = reader["name"].ToString();
                cat_name.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
                cat_name.LayoutTransform = new RotateTransform() { Angle = 90 };
                cat_expander.Header = cat_name;

                Thread t = new Thread(() => LoadUnderCategories(categoryID));
                t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                t.Start();
                t.Join();

                Border border = new Border();
                border.Width = 1;
                border.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
                border.SnapsToDevicePixels = true;
                border.Background = (Brush)FindResource("MaterialDesignDivider");

                cat_expander.Content = serviceList;
                serviceListSP.Children.Add(cat_expander);
                serviceListSP.Children.Add(border);

                serviceList.Items.Clear();
                #endregion
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

i try to pause the code using Threads to call LoadUnderCategories:

```
private void LoadUnderCategories(int categoryID)
{
    connection = new MySqlConnection(conf.connection_string);
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM auftrags_typ_childcategory WHERE category = @categoryID";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@categoryID", categoryID);

    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    {
        try
        {
            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                TreeViewItem child_category = new TreeViewItem();
                child_category.Header = reader["name"].ToString();
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    serviceList.Items.Add(child_category);
                }));

            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

I declared `TreeView serviceList = new TreeView();` global.

But the program freeze then. How I access to global `serviceList` when program freeze if I use `Dispatcher.Invoke` ?

Comment: Try to put the whole loop within the dispatcher instead of only the add function, you're calling the dispatcher in a loop and that may be part of the  issue.
Alternatively, try using BeginInvoke instead of Invoke (which is synchronous) it is possible that at one point your work thread will be waiting on UI thread and the UI thread waiting on the work thread, at the same time.

Comment: It still freezes.
Edit:
With BeginInvoke it works. But then it doesn't pause.
I have 3 subcategories. 2 has the id 1 and the last subcat has the id 2.
But all subcategories goes to the last category with id 4. So i think. t.Join doesn't work. Because the subcats will added to the last category.

Answer (score 0):

@Felype wrote in the comments to use `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke`.
This worked. The program don't freeze anymore. Thanks.

The other problem which i declared as answer in the comment is fixed too by:

```
TreeView serviceList = new TreeView();
Thread t = new Thread( () => LoadUnderCategories(categoryID, serviceList) );
```

And

```
private void LoadUnderCategories(int categoryID, TreeView serviceList)
```

Hope thats the right way.